# Attribute error in nested method

Tags: python

I have the following class:

```
class Connection(object):
    defaults = {
        'application_key':None,
    }


    def __init__(self, application_key="None"):
        self.application_key = application_key or Connection.defaults.get('application_key')

    def make_request(self, params=None, method=None):
        url = URL_FORMAT % {
            'params': params,
        }

        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Token token='+ self.application_key,
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        }

        if method == "get":
            request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

            if request.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            return request.json()
            else:
                raise APIError("%s status received (not 200)" % request.status_code)
        elif method == "post":
            request = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
            request.status_code == requests.codes.ok
            if request.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                return request.json()
            else:
                raise APIError("%s status received (not 200)" % request.status_code)


    def get_geofence(self):
        try:
            data = self.make_request('geofences', 'get')

            return data

        except APIError:
            raise GeofenceNotFound("Geofence not found")

    def get_geofence_id(self, geofence_id=None):
        try:
            data = self.make_request('geofences/'+self.geofence_id+'/', 'get')

            return data

        except APIError:
            raise GeofenceNotFound("Geofence not found with id #%s" % self.geofence_id)
```

The problem line seems to be `data = self.make_request('geofences/'+self.geofence_id+'/', 'get')` returning `AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'geofence_id'`

I'm pretty stumped here.

Comment: As far as I can see, your object has no such attribute.  Did you mean to use just `geofence_id` (with no self)?  That is the variable that you are passing into the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geofence_id` is not a class attribute, it is a function parameter. Thus, you should just refer to is as `geofence_id` and not `self.geofence_id`.